# calling method in template class in template member function of another class

Tags: c++, class, templates, return-type

I am having trouble on how to handle the template value return in the `get` method of the  `SetOfCells` class.

Is it possible to do it in the way shown below? What is the correct Syntax for doing this?  ( I use the `cellParent` pointer array to point to each cells)

```
template <class T>
class cell : public cellParent 
{
    .....
    T get() { return Val;}
    .....
private:
    T val;
};

class SetOfCells
{
    ....
    template<class T> T get(int cellIndex)
    {
       return cellArray[cellIndex]->get();
    }
    ....
private:
    cellParent**  cellArray;
};
```

Comment: Have you actually *tried* to do so?

Comment: `dynamic_cast<cell<T>*>(cellArray[cellIndex])->get();`

Comment: Maybe `return static_cast< cell<T>* >(cellArray[cellIndex])->get();`, but how would you know that the cast is valid?

Comment: @Siege, On the code given dynamic_cast doesn't work because there are no virtual functions.

Comment: You'll get better responses if you include all your code (ie cellParent definition), the compiler error you are getting, and best of all provide a short, self contained example - with a few more lines of code you could provide an example anyone could copy-paste into their compiler and try for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetOfCells` uses `cellParent` - which either does not define `template <class T> T get(int cellIndex)` or it defines it but it is not overridden in the `cell` class.

Note it is *not possible* to do what you are trying to do: you cannot override a template member function in C++.

So, my suggestion would be to have `SetOfCells` be a template class and have a `cell<T>**` member.

```
template <class T>
class SetOfCells
{
    ....
    T get(int cellIndex)
    {
       return cellArray[cellIndex]->get();
    }
    ....
private:
    cell<T>**  cellArray;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to do the template for SetOfCells as you said since I don't know the type of the cells. I was trying to get rid of the <type> in the declaration of SetOfCells in main. But it seems that I can't.
But, if I have cells of different type and I make them into an array using inheritance, how would I define the return type of the get function in SetOfCells to match the return type of each individual cells?

Comment: You can't easily achieve what you are trying to do - I'm guessing you want functionality like being able to have an array of ints, floats and double all mixed in together.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `boost::any` which does what your `cell` class is attempting - you want an array of `boost::any` types.
If you want to make your own version, read up on dynamic casting. Hope that helps!